# $this->container is always returning null

Tags: symfony

I am trying to get some services from container:

```
class MyController extends Controller
{
    private $service;
    public function __construct() {
       $this->service = $this->container->get("service");
    }
}
```

but container is null and throws an exception:

```
Error: Call to a member function get() on null
```

How can I make it works?
ps: I dont want to make my controller a service.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**EDIT**

You can't access the service container from the constructor, because the method `setContainer` has not been called yet.

Call the same in another method of your controller and it works.

Comment: This answer is wrong.
The error message is calling get() on null and the code is $this->container->get(); so the $this->container property is null. It is not a function call on $this. The answer below is correct. The container is being set by a setter injection later, so at the constrictor the container property is null, not yet set.

Answer (score 2):

To extend on the accepted answer.

When a service class is instantiated, first the constructor is called. The kernel/service container then checks if the object is an instance of `ContainerAware` then calls the method `setContainer`. The `$container` parameter is not available in the constructor.

If you want to do a one time initialization, like a constructor, override the method `setContainer` and do your container specific initialization there.